# How do I obtain ZPL command return value from code

Tags: vb6, zpl, zpl-ii

How do I get return value from a printer if I called this command in vb6, on Zebra Setup Utilities it will display information regarding about the printer. I try running this command and print nothing

`Printer.Print "${^XA^HH^XZ}$"
Printer.EndDoc`

Comment: Can you give some more context to what you are trying to do? What printer(s) are you working with? And what information do you want returned from the printer and why?

Comment: @EdHayes3 KR403 is the printer model and I want to obtain error value, printer information and etc. The command will return on zebra setup utilizes if you command in ^XA^HH^XZ except vb6 printer function does not work that way

Comment: Looks like its returned via a terminal emulator: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/HH_Command.pdf
 You can always try wireshark to see how the data is returned to the client.

Comment: I see you have recently deleted some questions. There is no way for me to contact you. I think I can help you on how to callback a vb6 module from c# module passing parameters in an asynchronous way. I were going to answer while you delete your post. If you publish it again I can tell you my answer

Comment: @AlessandroCiurlo is cool I solved it already, I delete cause is going no where anymore. Thanks tho!